# no se envia formulario desde safari

Tags: php, formularios, safari

tengo un formulario de contacto con php y funciona perfecto, excepto en safari... me da la aprovación "su mensaje fue enviado con exito!" pero nunca llega! Es necesario alguna linea que haga compatible a safari? o porque puede ser que ocurra esto. Paso lo que estoy usando en el formulario.

**HTML**

```
<div id="correo">
    <p>Envianos un mail</p>
    <div id="contact_form">
    <form action="confFormulario3.php" id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
        <input type="text" id="email" class="boton" name="email" placeholder="Tu email">
        <input type="text" id="nombre" class="boton" name="nombre" placeholder="Cómo te llamas">
        <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" class="boton"  placeholder="En qué podemos ayudarte?"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="buttonEnviar" class="boton" value="ENVIAR">
    </form>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
/*Capturamos las variables del POST con operadores ternarios*/
$email=   filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
$name=    ( empty($_POST["nombre"])    )  ?  NULL : $_POST["nombre"];
$message= ( empty($_POST["mensaje"]) )  ?  NULL : $_POST["mensaje"];
/*Verificamos que los tres datos fueron posteados*/
if ($email && $name && $message){
   $para = 'timondigitalweb@gmail.com';
   $asunto = "mensaje de la web de TIMON!!!!!!!!!!!!";
   $mailheader = "From: ".$email."\r\n";
   $mailheader .= "Reaply-To:".$email."\r\n";
   $mailheader .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";

   $MESSAGE_BODY = "Nombre: ".$name."\n";
   $MESSAGE_BODY .= "\n<br>Email: ".$email."\n";
   $MESSAGE_BODY .= "\n<br>Mensaje: ".nl2br($message)."\n";

   mail($para, $asunto, $MESSAGE_BODY, $mailheader) or die("error al enviar mensaje, intente nuevamente");
   echo "<script>
       alert('Gracias por tu contacto! en breves nos estaremos comunicando 2');
              window.location='index.php'
              </script>";


 }else{
    //Aquí puedes también redirigir con un mensaje de error
    echo "<script>
        alert('Upss! parece que algo no quedo bien completado, por favor completa nuevamente los datos y vuelve a intentar enviar el mensaje');
               window.location='contacto.php'
              </script>";
 }
?>
```

Comment: El texto *su mensaje fue enviado con exito!*  no aparece en ninguna parte del código que muestras. ¿Ese es el código realmente o es otro? Y, ¿intentaste limpiar la caché de Safari: `Preferencias / Privacidad / Gestionar datos del sitio web` y allí seleccionas el sitio y limpias la caché o bien en el menú `Desarrollo`
?

Comment: tu código funciona.. tienes un error tipográfico: `Reaply-To` debe ser `Reply-To`..  y te recomiendo usar [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: @BlackSheep ¿crees que eso sería motivo para que no funcione en Safari? Me parece que es más bien un problema de caché. Aunque está claro que debe corregir lo que indicas, pues tendrá problemas cuando se intente responder a los mensajes.

Comment: @A.Cedano - Nada que ver con los navegadores...(al menos no tendría lógica ya que como sabrás PHP es el lado del servidor) ... es mas bien la función `mail()` y/o la configuración del servidor...

Comment: @BlackSheep, al inicio de la pregunta dice que funciona perfecto, excepto en Safari, de ahí mi comentario/pregunta. Puede que su Safari tenga en caché una versión antigua de esa página donde el código era erróneo y sea eso lo que hace que no funcione. Además, el mensaje que dice que muestra no aparece en ese código.

Comment: @A.Cedano - Dudo que sea el cache...pero nada es imposible... y si es otro código pues nada... ya nos informará...  y que mire también en la carpeta de SPAM etc... no se puede fiar de la función `mail()`  por eso la recomendación de PHPMailer....

Comment: @A.Cedano y Black Sheep, gracias por su interes. Estuve realizando prueba con otros iphone y me llegaron perfecto... no sabria explicar que es lo que fallaba. Igualmente voy a corregir el error de tipeo y a investigar sobre PHPMailer para evitar futuras fallas. Nuevamente muchas gracias y perdonen la demora en la repuesta he estado complicada. Saludos

Comment: @BlackSheep El mensaje que figura al enviar el formulario fue un error al tipear la pregunta. Quise poner que el código tomaba como exitoso el envío y no tuve en cuenta el poner literal el mensaje que se muestra, perdón por la confusión